# How to automatize uploading files process in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just learning so forgive me if my question is transparent. Now I've got in *controller*:

```
$scope.fileUrl = 'test/data_1.zip';
$scope.fileName = 'myData';
```

In *html*:

```
<a href="{{fileUrl}}" download="{{fileName}}"> Download version 1 </a>
```

So, maybe tomorrow I'll add in folder *test* file *data_2.zip*... and then over and over again. Hence I will be forced to write almost the same line in the *html* & *controller* many times... How can I automatize that process? I hope what I have requested is possible, any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can store all your files in an array and iterate overthem with `ng-repeat`:

```
$scope.files = [{
        url: 'test/data_1.zip',
        name: 'myData'
    }, {
        url: 'test/data_2.zip',
        name: 'myData2'
    }, ... ];
```

in your html you write:

```
<a href="{{file.url}}" download="{{file.name}}" ng-repeat="file in files"> Download version 1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your naming is consistent you use this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in array">
    <a href="test/data_{{$index+1}}.zip" download="{{fileName}}{{$index+1}}"> Download version {{$index + 1}} </a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var numberOfFiles = 12;
$scope.array = new Array(numberOfFiles);
$scope.fileName = 'myData';
```

You are creating "n" number of download links and only replacing the number at the end of the file. e.g. `test/data_#.zip`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5812/

Comment: Man, thank you too, it works for me. But @chresse was first :)

Comment: No problem, use whatever suits your application best.